# ASP.NET HTML table to XLSX including styling?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I would like to ask If there is an open-source library that would allow me to convert HTML table to .Xlsx format including styling. The project I am working with generates expandable/collapsable tables, however, I'd like to export them to excel in .xlsx format. I came across a few libraries, but none of them is fully open source. I will appreciate any advice.

Comment: I vote to close, due to "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more"

Comment: use NPOI.  (C# version of apache POI)  You can create cell styles... XSSFCellStyle... https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi